# What does the initial param set in router-link

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

Iam trying to make a service with Vuejs.
Here is the router-link and I'd like to make a dynamic url with each user's ID.
As you can see, named route 'profile' has an initial param "0".
However, I do not need to put "0" because this params will be needed when user post ajax request.

RestAPI Controller function

→index()...getAllUsersProfiles()

→show($id)...getUsersProfileById($id)

First, I tried {user_id : " "} in router-link but ".../profile/list/undefined" was returned and of course I can not call api. Anyway, even though parameter "0" is not match for user_id, I have to put some number as an initial parameter to avoid "undefined".

index.vue

```
<router-link tag="li" :to="{name: 'profile', params: {user_id : '0'}}"><button class="btn btn-success">profile</button></router-link>
```

app.js

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        { path: '*', component: NotFoundComponent },
        { path: '/top', name: 'top', component: require('./components/TopView.vue') },
        { path: '/profile/list/:user_id', name: 'profile', component: require('./components/ProfileList.vue') },
    ]
})
```

Is there any way to deal " "case and "2 or 3 or...(user_id)"case in one route?

Comment: Your router-link component is trying to link to a route with `name` of `'profile'`. But, you don't have a route with that name. Did you mean `'profiles'`?

Comment: yes, sorry just a mistake. hmm...is there any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Seems like you want to know how your `ProfileList` component is supposed to handle its `user_id` parameter. But I can't really tell. Can you clarify your question?